# Move Django 1.11 project to wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

Please help, I could find error. 
I'm using django 1.11 and apache (on centos)

There is my wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys    
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/var/project/project_python35_venv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

my django.conf (of httpd)

```
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIDaemonProcess project user=apache group=apache processes=10 threads=10 maximum-requests=10000 python-path=/var/project/project_python35_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages python-home=/var/project/project_python35_venv/lib/python3.5
#WSGIProcessGroup project
#WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
#WSGIPythonHome /var/project/project_python35_venv/lib/python3.5

<VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory /var/project/project_python35_venv>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/project-access.log common
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/project-error.log

DocumentRoot /var/project/project/project/

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/project/project/project/wsgi.py

Alias /static /var/project/project/project/static/

<Directory /var/project/project/project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/project/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying all cases, but still got this error on my log of httpd :

> ImportError: No module named site

Thank you all for the help

Comment: Did you compile mod_wsgi yourself from source code? How did you compile mod_wsgi if you did? Where is the Python installation you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

wsgi

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = '/var/project'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
def execfile(filename):
     globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
     exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'project_python35_venv/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and apache.conf

```
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/var/project/project/:/var/project_python35_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup project

<VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory /var/project/project_python35_venv>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/project-access.log common
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/project-error.log

DocumentRoot /var/project/project/

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/project/project/wsgi.py

Alias /var/project/project/static /var/project/project/static/

<Directory /var/project/project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for recommended way of using Python virtual environments with mod_wsgi. You should avoid using ``python-path`` with ``site-packages``, use ``python-home`` with root of virtual environment instead. When done in Apache configuration, don't need ``activate_this`` in WSGI script file.

Comment: Also, setting ``DocumentRoot`` to be directory above where your source code is a bad idea. Muck up configuration and that can mean your source code is downloadable.